# Swagger UI disappeared after switching to Neo4j (show 'Database' instead Swagger)

Tags: neo4j, swagger, jhipster

I switched **Jhispter** microservices app to Neo4j, all works fine, but after switching I have 'Database' in menu instead Swagger menu (in Gateway interface).
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ckAx.png)

Did somebody face with this issue? How to return Swagger interface to Gateway web app?

Thanks.

Comment: Database has not replaced API docs, it was already there, it's just that API docs has disappeared. Are you sure you are running gateway with swagger profile? https://www.jhipster.tech/profiles/

Comment: Hi, yes I run with swagger profile, we fixed it on front-end part. Thanks.